# css subclasses - divs not matching css rules

Tags: css, html, subclass

For some reason my subclass will not work on DIV elements?

The CSS rules match inline tags like span + a but it will not match div.

Please look at the example below:

```
<style>

.row {
    display: block;
}

.row .lbl {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: blue;
}

.row .inpt {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: red;
}


</style>
```

WORKS!!!

```
<p class="row">

    <span class="lbl">Title</span>
    <span class="inpt">Data</span> 

</p>
```

DOES NOT WORK!!!

```
<p class="row">

    <div class="lbl">Title</div>
    <div class="inpt">Data</div> 

</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the P element, w3.org specifies the following, which indicates that P elements are only allowed to contain inline elements.

```
<!ELEMENT P - O (%inline;)*            -- paragraph -->
```

This is consistent with http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1, which says that the P element "cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself)."

Comment: hope you understand that it is not allowed!

Answer (score 1):

I believe because your `div` is a child of a `p`. If you change your `p` to a `div` it works again.

Comment: yeah it will work but the question is why it will not work with the code he used!